# Getting the annotations of the calling method

Tags: java, reflection

Here is an example of my code:

```
class foo extends afoo{

    @HTTPPost
    returnClass runTransaction(RequestData req){
        return sendData(req, returnClass.class)
    }

    @HTTPGet
    returnClass runTransaction2(RequestData req){
        return sendData(req, returnClass.class)
    }
}


abstract class afoo {

public <T> T sendData(ARestMessage req, Class<T> returnClassType)
    //here i need the annotation of the calling method
}
```

Basically i'm building a pretty complex messaging system and I want to put as much of the switching and configuration in annotations as i can.

Yes, I know there are a few libraries out there (like Google reflection) that would make this easier but in order for me to use them I have to do 4-6 months of paperwork and meetings with Enterprise Architecture to get approval to use them.  Seeing the project must be finished in 2 months, i'm doing it by hand.

So what i'm doing is creating annotations that developers can annotate the methods with indicating the way the resulting service is expecting the data to be sent.  That could be a get, post, put, etc.  Inside the abstract class, that all service classes extend, is a senddata method.  That method must be able to figure out which method was used to call it, aka, was it by runTransaction or runTransaction2, so sendData pull that methods annotations and therefore know exactly how to send the data to the service.

now I found this (which is the first line of code in my sendData method)

```
final Method callingMethod = this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
```

But it keeps returning null.  i've read the javadoc on it several times and i'm not understanding why it keeps returning null.

I understand that I can get the parent caller using the stack, but I would prefer not to do that because this application shares app server memory with another application that does a TON of AOP work.  That AOP work is really good at messing up stacks in unintended ways, so I would rather solve this using straight reflection.

Does anyone know why this method keeps returning null? Is it because its contained in an abstract class and not my foo class itself?  Is there a way to accomplish this using the techniques I would prefer to use?

thanks

Comment: See Perception's answer for the reason why.  If you are already using AOP can you not move whatever logic you need to do in another aspect?

Comment: No, thats another project that just happens to be sharing the same server.  At least until they get their own machine which could happen in 1 week, 5 years, who knows.  We are not using aspects in this project due to the big problems they had with the previous project.  Enterprise Architecture didn't care that the implementation was flawed from the word go, they just saw major problems and killed the technology.

Answer (score 4):

The method `Class.getEnclosingMethod()` does not do what you think it does. Here is the Javadoc for it:

> If this Class object represents a local or anonymous class within a
>   method, returns a Method object representing the immediately enclosing
>   method of the underlying class. **Returns null otherwise**. In particular,
>   this method returns null if the underlying class is a local or
>   anonymous class immediately enclosed by a type declaration, instance
>   initializer or static initializer.

Specifically, it returns the outer, enclosing method for an anonymous inner class, that was defined in the context of that method. I did not see anywhere in your description that these messaging methods are being called from anonymous/local inner classes. Here is an example in code (jUnit required):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

interface Introspector {
    public Method getEnclosingMethod();
}

public class Encloser {

    public Encloser() {
        super();
    }

    public Method noop() {

        final Introspector inner = new Introspector() {
            @Override
            public Method getEnclosingMethod() {
                return getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
            }
        };

        return inner.getEnclosingMethod();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEnclosingMethods() throws Exception {
        final Encloser encloser = new Encloser();
        Method method = encloser.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
        Assert.assertNull(method);

        method = encloser.noop();
        Assert.assertNotNull(method);
    }
}
```

Your current solution sounds pretty complicated. Are you planning on walking up the method call chain (which you can only do by dumping the stacktrace btw) and looking for annotations after doing some hefty reflection? I foresee alot of bugs. Frankly, employing some kind of builder pattern would probably be better for your scenario.

Comment: I read that at least a dozen times before I posted the question and I still don't get it.  the afoo class is not an anonymous class and its not a local class (that I know of).  Its an abstract class that is being extended by another public class.

Comment: I am trying to keep it as simple as possible, trust me.  I only need to go up one level.  Im giving this approach another half day of work, if I can't get this to work, I intend on going to a more classical factory style design.  Im just hoping that this method allows me to hide the complexities into abstract classes in the system and the developers simply need to annotate things to indicate how they want a message sent.

Comment: And bugs are why I do not want to go the stack route.  I'm hoping something hidden in the deep bowels of reflection will allow me to determine was it foo.runTransaction, foo.runTransaction2, bar.runTransaction, or bar.runTransaction2 that called the sendData method

Comment: @scphantm - I added a code example, hopefully its easier to follow. Quick question, what are you planning on doing differently in your target method, based on which calling method invoked it?

Comment: If the parent method is annotated HTTPPost, then send the data via post, if its annotated HTTPGet, run a few other methods to gather security information and format the url and send it via get.  The individual methods work just fine, i'm simply trying to create a pretty much transparent way of telling the logic which one to use.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand the use case for getEnclosingMethod now.  Got it, yea that doesn't help me very much for my problem.  Its looking to me like I will have to use a factory class of some kind, it doesn't look like im going to be able to do it with reflection without going to the stack.  Thats a bummer.  Unless anyone else has any ideas.....   Thanks

Comment: Even though I hate global state, that is one alternative to using the builder pattern. Alternatively, if you have some kind of IoC framework (CDI, Guice, Spring), then you basically have ***no problem*** at all - just inject appropriately scoped beans into your callee and caller, after having populated the beans with data in the caller.

Comment: yea, I hate global state too, in this environment under the load this app will be getting, that would be a nightmare.  Spring is an option, I have to see what version i'm allowed to use.  If 3.x is on the approved list then I may use that, if Enterprise insists on 2.X, i will simply use a factory class.  But hey, it was a worth while question, I learned something that won't work and in my world, that is just as valuable as what will work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point using annotation here, just pass another argument to method `sendData()`.

Comment: That's what i'm probably going to end up doing, or a factory class of some kind, I was just hoping to begin building a system where annotations can be used to govern how things are processed.  I have had great success with using annotations to accomplish exactly that, to this point. This was the last major roadblock in executing my plan for world domination.  But its looking like I have to go with a more traditional route.

Comment: +1 simple, and correct answer. Callee should not know anything about caller.